# ajax php always returning null

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Hi im trying to use multple ajax functions which im not sure is possible.

my first one is called when your typing your username

```
onkeyup="UsernameTaken(this.value);"
```

the other one is called in the body with

```
onload="BattlePlayers();"
```

the functions are like this

```
    var xhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
function UsernameTaken(name){
    if (name == "") {
        document.getElementById("UsernameTaken").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("UsernameTaken").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "CheckUsername.php?q="+name, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
function BattlePlayers(){
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("BattleTable").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "GetPlayers.php", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

then the php for the battleplayer which seems to always return blank is this

```
   <?php
$link = mysqli_connect("","","","");
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        $x = 0; 
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM userstats ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5; ";
            $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
            $toecho ="";
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                if($row['username'] !== $_SESSION['username']){//add so it dosent put duplicates
                    $toecho .="<tr>";
                    $toecho .="<th>".$row['username']." </th>";
                    $toecho .="<th>Level: ".$row['Level']." </th>";
                    $toecho .="<th>Player Stats:".$row['Attack']."/".$row['Defence']." </th>";
                    $toecho .="<th>Win Chance: ";
                    $toecho .= CalculateWinChance($link,$row['Defence']);
                    $toecho .="<input type='hidden' name='hidden1' value='".$row['Defence']."' />";
                    $toecho .="<input type='hidden' name='hidden2' value='".$row['username']."' />";
                    $toecho .="<th><input type ='submit' name = 'Attack_Btn' value ='Attack'></th>";
                    $toecho .="</tr>";
                }
            }
            echo $toecho;
        }
?>
```

it does not seem to get to the battleplayers at all i have tried echoing an alert from getplayers with nothing coming up. i have confirmed that the javascript is being called by making that alert at different stages. its just when it reaches the getplayers that is just seems to stop. what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Where is `session_start()`?

Comment: thats at the top of my index page in my main php area

Comment: you need to include `session_start()` at the top of `GetPlayers.php` too

Comment: oh cool thankyou did not know that. you can put it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think logically about what your ajax request is doing then you'll realise that if the page being called via ajax needs access to session variables then, because it is effectively a distinct request separate from the page that initiated the request, you will need to include `session_start()` on that script.

If you had a standard php page like:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    include 'functions.php';
    include 'classes.php';
    include 'GetPlayers.php';
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- stuff -->
    </body>
</html>
```

In the above example page your script `GetPlayers.php` WOULD have access to the session.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    include 'functions.php';
    include 'classes.php';
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                if( xhr.status==200 && xhr.readyState==4 ){
                    alert( xhr.response );
                }
            };
            xhr.open( 'GET','GetPlayers.php',true );
            xhr.send();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Whereas here, without `session_start()` at the top of `GetPlayers.php` the two pages do not share the same session and hence when the script checks for `if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {.....}` it will fail.